# Detecting a checkered/chessboard pattern, in an image, and extrapolating it across the entire image - Python

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration

As shown in this image:

[As shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRzMr.jpg)

I have a 3D printed, L shaped chessboard pattern. Each individual square is 10x10mm. My python code should detect this pattern in an uploaded image (no matter the orientation, and even from different angles, i.e. even when image distortion/parallax is at play). The detected pattern should then be used to artificially cast a net across the entire image, to give an idea of distortions and scale. The user should then be able to draw a line on the image, which should be evaluated in length against the artificially created net (given square side lengths of 10mm).

The returns should be: the original image with the net cast over it, the net by itself, and the calculated length of the drawn line.

I have tried using a variety of code, it never detects the chessboard accurately, nor does it evaluate the length of the line accurately (not even close).
The most recent code I used is shown below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, PhotoImage
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def intersects(self, other):
        return not (self.x + self.width < other.x or
                    other.x + other.width < self.x or
                    self.y + self.height < other.y or
                    other.y + other.height < self.y)

def load_image():
    Tk().withdraw()  # Prevents the root window from appearing
    file_path = askopenfilename(title="Select an image file", filetypes=[("Image files", "*.png;*.jpg;*.jpeg")])
    if not file_path:
        print("No file selected. Exiting.")
        exit()
    return cv2.imread(file_path)

def detect_white_rectangles(image):
    # Convert image to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Threshold the image to detect white regions
    _, thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Find contours in the thresholded image
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # Filter contours based on area to get rectangles
    rectangles = [cv2.boundingRect(contour) for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 500]

    return rectangles

def plot_rectangles(image, rectangles):
    image_with_rectangles = image.copy()
    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        cv2.rectangle(image_with_rectangles, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_rectangles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("Detected White Rectangles")
    plt.show()

def plot_detected_squares(image, rectangles):
    image_with_rectangles = image.copy()
    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        cv2.rectangle(image_with_rectangles, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_rectangles, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("Detected White Squares")
    plt.show()

def extrapolate_pattern(image, rectangles):
    pattern_image = np.zeros_like(image)
    alternate = True
    for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
        if alternate:
            pattern_image[y:y + h, x:x + w] = [255, 255, 255]
        else:
            pattern_image[y:y + h, x:x + w] = [0, 0, 0]
        alternate = not alternate

    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(pattern_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("Extrapolated Pattern of Detected Squares")
    plt.show()

def calculate_line_length(x1, y1, x2, y2, scale_factor=1.0):
    # Calculate the Euclidean distance between two points
    length = np.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) * scale_factor
    return length

def draw_line(image, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    canvas = Canvas()
    canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="red", width=2)
    photo = PhotoImage(width=image.shape[1], height=image.shape[0])
    canvas.create_image((image.shape[1] / 2, image.shape[0] / 2), image=photo, state="normal")
    canvas.update()

def intersected_squares(line, rectangles):
    intersected = 0
    for rect in rectangles:
        if line.intersects(rect):
            intersected += 1
    return intersected

def generate_artificial_squares(image, pattern_size=30):
    artificial_image = np.zeros_like(image)

    # Calculate the number of rows and columns based on the image size and pattern size
    rows = image.shape[0] // pattern_size
    cols = image.shape[1] // pattern_size

    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            x = j * pattern_size
            y = i * pattern_size
            cv2.rectangle(artificial_image, (x, y), (x + pattern_size, y + pattern_size), (255, 255, 255), -1)

    return artificial_image

def main():
    # Load image
    image = load_image()

    # Detect white rectangles
    rectangles = detect_white_rectangles(image)

    # Display original image with rectangles
    plot_rectangles(image, rectangles)

    # Display image with only detected squares
    plot_detected_squares(image, rectangles)

    # Extrapolate pattern of squares across the entire image
    extrapolate_pattern(image, rectangles)

    # Generate artificial squares in the same pattern
    artificial_squares = generate_artificial_squares(image)

    # Plot artificial squares
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(artificial_squares, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.title("Artificial Squares in the Same Pattern")
    plt.show()

    # Allow the user to draw a line and calculate its length
    print("Draw a line on the image by clicking two points.")
    print("Press 'q' to finish drawing and calculate the length.")
    
    # Create a copy of the image for drawing
    image_to_draw = image.copy()

    # Initialize variables for line coordinates
    line_points = []

    # Create a callback function to handle mouse events
    def draw_line_callback(event, x, y, flags, param):
        nonlocal line_points
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            line_points.append((x, y))
            if len(line_points) == 2:
                # Draw the line on the image
                cv2.line(image_to_draw, line_points[0], line_points[1], (0, 0, 255), 2)
                # Calculate the length of the drawn line
                scale_factor = 1.0 / 10.0  # Scale factor based on the assumption that each square has side lengths of 10mm
                length = calculate_line_length(line_points[0][0], line_points[0][1], line_points[1][0], line_points[1][1], scale_factor)
                print(f"The length of the drawn line is approximately {length:.2f} mm.")
                # Reset the line_points list for the next line
                line_points = []

    # Create a window and set the callback function for mouse events
    cv2.namedWindow("Draw Line")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("Draw Line", draw_line_callback)

    while True:
        # Display the image with the drawn line
        cv2.imshow("Draw Line", image_to_draw)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        # Check for 'q' key to finish drawing
        if key == ord('q'):
            break

    # Close the window and clean up
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: your entire code contains nothing I recognize to be "detecting a chessboard". -- that's not a proper chessboard. that's something L-shaped. opencv does not have functions to locate the corners/saddle points of such a thing. -- what's the point of 3d-printing this? you can just print the pattern on a sheet of paper. the corners will be more precisely localizable. you just have to measure what the printer actually made. it can be off by a percent or a few, in each dimension. measure across the entire pattern, not along a single square.

Comment: The point behind 3D printing is that it should give users a more durable piece than simply a printed paper, which could crumble, bend, etc. In the end my aim is to use this L shaped piece to serve as a scale for size, angle and distortion on the image, and use it to approximate distance on the image and be able to "measure digitally".

Comment: Do you have any idea(algorithm) to achieve your purpose if you can recognize your L-pattern? If no, trying to recognize some pattern without "how to use the result of recognition" is meaningless.

Comment: printed patterns can be glued to cardboard/MDF/plywood/acrylic/... and there are companies that specialize in manufacturing very accurate calibration targets. the usual 3D-printing will give you accuracy no better than 0.1-0.3 mm due to the the molten plastic squeezing out of a nozzle, displacing the molten plastic that is laid down beside it on the same layer. -- I would strongly recommend just printing this, measuring it (across all squares), sticking it to some rigid board with double-sided tape. don't use any liquid glue. that'll soak into the paper and make it expand.